# UIScrollView inside another inside a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

The app I'm working on has a view to display the details of "items". The details take enough space that the detail view needs to be scrollable vertically. Part of the details is a set of images, displayed one by one in a horizontally scrollable subview. And finally, the user needs to be able to pan the screen horizontally to change the item that is being displayed.

The way I have implemented this is to have a `UIPageViewController` to handle the changing of the item, with a view controller that handles displaying the item details. The item details are in an `UIScrollView`, and the image view is another `UIScrollView` inside this with paging enabled.

The problem with this setup is that when the image view has been scrolled all the way to one end so that it cannot be scrolled anymore in that direction, I would like panning on the image view to affect the page view controller so that the view would scroll to the next item, and that is not happening. The image view scrolls, as does the detail view itself. The panning to change the item works in other parts of the screen, just not on the image view.

I made an example project to demonstrate the issue. The code of the main `UIViewController` is

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPageViewController *pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    pageController.dataSource = self;
    [self addChildViewController:pageController];
    [self.view addSubview:pageController.view];
    pageController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [pageController setViewControllers:@[[[ItemViewController alloc] init]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return [[ItemViewController alloc] init];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return [[ItemViewController alloc] init];
}

@end
```

And the code of the item view controller is

```
@implementation ItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *imageView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    imageView.bounces = NO;
    imageView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    imageView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    imageView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    UILabel *longText = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    longText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:28.0];
    longText.text = @"AAAASSSSDDDDFFFFGGGGHHHHJJJJKKKKLLLL";
    longText.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [longText sizeToFit];
    [imageView addSubview:longText];
    imageView.contentSize = longText.bounds.size;

    UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mainScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    mainScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 2 * CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))];
    [contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [mainScrollView addSubview:contentView];
    mainScrollView.contentSize = contentView.bounds.size;
    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
}

@end
```

I have also experimented with this code with the following findings:

- If I leave out `mainScrollView`, i.e., I add only `imageView` as a subview of `self.view`, the paging works. It keeps working even when `longText` is short enough to fit completely into the screen.
- If I make `contentView` wider than the screen, even by 1 point, the paging works again, though I need to pan the `mainScrollView` to the end of its content. But with `contentView` only as wide as the screen, the paging does not happen.

From the latter observation it would seem that `UIScrollView` swallows the panning gesture in a direction where it cannot be scrolled. But this doesn't explain why in the first case, with `imageView` being the only visible view, the paging works even when the scroll view is not scrollable.